# What are the required platform to make mobile app that has dapp features?

Tags: blockchain, dapps, react, android, ios

I recently went over dapp with ethereum block chain but most of the coureses and documentation follows example in webApps. I want to know what are the possible frameworks/library, technology/ languages etc that i would need if i want to develop a android/ios app that has dapp feature of implementing smart contracts and communication with the ethereum or any other network.

P.S. for cross-platform development i wanted to use react native and would to work with domains that are compatible with react-native

Answer (score 0):

Use [Uno Platform](https://platform.uno/) with [Nethereum](https://nethereum.com/)